# Convert .csv to .out (complex numbers)

Tags: matlab, csv, file-upload, complex-numbers

I have a csv file that has complex numbers.

This is sample of some numbers I have in the csv file:

```
(0.12825663763789857+0.20327998150393212j),(0.21890748607218197+0.160563964013564j),(0.28205414129281525+0.09884068776334366j),(0.030927026479380615+0.26334550583848626j)
```

I want to read this file and then save in (.out) file all the real parts in the first column and all the imaginary parts in the second column (without the imaginary letter j).

Comment: You could use [readmatrix](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html) to read the file, [real](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) to get the real part of the number and, for example, [writematrix](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) to write the real parts to a file. 

If you run into problems, show us what you have tried and what does not work.

Comment: @PatrickHappel There is no readmatrix function in my matlab version (R2017b)

Comment: For version prior to 2019a, use [csvread](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html).

Comment: @PatrickHappel, I got the following error: ............................................... Error using dlmread (line 147)
Mismatch between file and format character vector.
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row
number 1, field number 1) ==>
(0.12825663763789857+0.20327998150393212j),(0.21890748607218197+0.160563964013564j),(0.28205414129281525+0.09884068776334366j),(0.030927026479380615+0.26334550583848626j),(-0.04689936501211118+0.25553...

Error in csvread (line 48)
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);

Error in graph_plot (line 9)
M = csvread('sol360.csv');

Comment: Are the numbers in your csv-file all in one line?

Comment: @PatrickHappel, yes all the complex number are stored in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one attempt. It is slightly more complicated due to the `(` and `)` that surround your numbers.

First, use [textscan](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read the file. Since I guess you don't know how many numers are in the file, read everything into a singe string. Will work with mutiple lines, too:

```
filename = 'data.csv';
fid = fopen(filename);
content = textscan(fid, '%s');
fclose(fid);
```

For this purpose, `content` now is a slightly weird `cell` array (look at the `textscan`-docs for details). Just initialize the variable `nums` which will store the numbers and loop through `content` (if you know a bit more about your csv file, you might pre-allocate `nums`):

```
nums = []; 
for c1 = 1:numel(content{1})
```

Next, split the string at every occurence of `,`:

```
    string_list = strsplit(content{1}{c1},',');
```

This gives another cell array. Loop through it to convert the strings to numbers (and end the outer loop):

```
    for c2 = 1 : numel(string_list)
        nums(end+1) = str2num(string_list{c2});
    end
end
```

Last, just store the real and the imaginary part of the numbers in separate columns:

```
out = [];
out(:,1) = real(nums);
out(:,2) = imag(nums);
```

and save it to `data.out`.
**Update** As you mentioned precision, you could use

```
dlmwrite('data.out', out, 'precision','%.20f');
```

However, here you need to understand the [floating point representation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) in Matlab. In particular, try to  understand the following:

```
>> a = 0.12825663763789857

a =

    0.1283

>> fprintf('%.20f\n', a)
0.12825663763789857397
>> eps(a)

ans =

   2.7756e-17
```

Note that one could have done this without cenverting the strings to numbers, but the way above would allow you to use the data in Matlab instead of just saving it.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I will try to read this out file in my code an see if everything works well. Thx again!

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly well, but I just want to know how can I save the complete digits of the complex number rather only the short format?

Comment: I think this has solved it, dlmwrite('data_new.out', out,  'precision', '%i')... but what if I want the full precession to be written?

Comment: I have edited my answer and posted a second one which does not convert the strings into numbers.

Comment: Since you are a new user, allow me to note the follwing: If you find one of the answers useful, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

HEre is an attempt without converting your strings to numbers, therefore one does not have to deal with precision. It works with negative real and imaginary numbers, too. `+` signs are removed when written to the new file, `-` signs are preserved:

```
filename = 'data.csv';
fid = fopen(filename);
content = textscan(fid, '%s');
fclose(fid);
fid = fopen('data.out','w');
pattern = '(?<real>-{0,1}\d+.\d+)(?<imag>[+-]\d+.\d+)j';
for c1 = 1:numel(content{1})
    result = regexp(content{1}{c1}, pattern, 'names');
    for c2 = 1:numel(result)
        fprintf(fid, '%s,%s\n', strrep(result(c2).real,'+',''), strrep(result(c2).imag,'+',''));
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```